# .htaccess url-rewrite if file not exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, file-exists

I must do a little trick for a site!
The idea is:

- if a file for a required url exists then I go to that url, doing nothing more;
- if a file for a required url not exists, I must go to a file.php and than do something, but NOT changing the url!

example:

www.mysite.com/page1.htm -> exists -> go to file page1.htm

www.mysite.com/page2.htm -> NOT exists -> go to file default.php but with url "www.mysite.com/page2.htm"

It's possible to do this all by .htaccess?

Comment: Also, give yourself a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to address you in their comments and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Comment: Thx for suggestions. I'm not always in this site. I'll try to correct my mistakes :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /default.php [L]
```

Comment: Some explanation would have been awesome.

Comment: I believe it's self explanatory. Other than including a link to mod_rewrite documentation, what more could I have done?

Answer (score 10):

It is not mentioned here but [FallbackResource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) is the new recommended way of **handling not-found (404) URLs**. Example:

```
FallbackResource /not-404.php
```

From **Apache manual**:

> Use this to set a handler for any URL that doesn't map to anything in your filesystem, and would otherwise return HTTP 404 (Not Found).

Comment: Important to note, I have found that this can break some server side processed REST-style URLs, like: `http://example.com/app.php/some/resource`.

Comment: That's not correct. Behavior of `FallbackResource` will be same as `ErrorDocument`. If `PATH_INFO` is enabled then `/app.php/some/resource`  works flawlessly and I've tested it on my Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Implement a 404 error rule. Doesn't require mod_rewrite:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /default.php
```

Comment: This is also great if you want to use an HTML5 fallback without messing up rest style calls to php like `http://example.com/app.php/some/resource`.

Comment: I actually switched to this and it worked even better!

Comment: This might NOT be what you want. This will send a HTTP 404 status (file not found) header back to the browser (and to Google). 
So only use it for a useful 'file not found' page.