# .htaccess if URL is bad do something

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm making my personal [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system). I want to use in it cool (friendly) URLs. This is my .htaccess file code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9_/]+)/?$ index.php?args=$1 [L]
```

I see that on Stack Overflow friendly URLs are also used. Today I tried to make an error on Stack Overflow. To (for example) this URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469955/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-file-not-exists`. I added `.php`. But I didn't see a 404 error. Our forum in a magic method deleted my postscript and redirected me back to correct site URL. **How can I make the same in my CMS**?

I tried to change this (`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9_/]+)/?$ index.php?args=$1 [L]`) line to (`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9_/]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9)$ index.php?args=$1 [L]`), but this isn't helpful and then I see `500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to have the same behavior as Stack Overflow then you got to have some server-side support (e.g. PHP, ASP, etc.) as well. Consider the following code snippet:

#### .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### index.php:

```
<?php
   $id    = $_GET['id'];
   $title = $_GET['title'];

   $dbTitle = // Get title from Database query using $id
   ...
   if ($title != $dbTitle) {
      // Redirect with 301 to correct /<id>/<title> page
      header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
      header('Location: /' . $id . '/' . $dbTitle);
      exit;
   }
   // The rest of your script
?>
```

Comment: what are NC and QSA flags ?

Comment: NC - No Case Comparison and QSA - Query String Append. Pls check this official docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html