# How can i write if condition statement in htaccess - Apache 2.2.15

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using a couple of folders outside Wordpress and if a file doesn't exist i want to show a custom 404 file (not the 404 standart Wordpress page). In these folders i have a .htaccess with only 2 lines "RewriteOptions Inherit" and "ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.php". It's working, but the problem is that sometime some ads banner are not using their domain in their script, and i have errors in my log.

```
[the_date] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /home/admin/web/my_domain.com/public_html/folder_outside_wordpress/undefined, referer: http://my_domain.com/folder_outside_wordpress/my_file.php
```

Basically, if in their scripts is something like `/folder/file.php` instead of `http://ads-domain.com/folder/file.php` i got errors in my log file, as is right to be because im using `RewriteOptions Inherit`.
So, my point is to use line "RewriteOptions Inherit" only when the requested file is missing, something like this.

```
if (status == 404)
{
RewriteOptions Inherit
ErrorDocument 404 /err/404.php
}
```

Apache version 2.2.15

Answer (score 0):

I have found another [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469955/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-file-not-exists) without using `RewriteOptions Inherit`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /err/404.php [L]
```