# error message showing when url is not found

Tags: php, url

I want to call a file by an url. If the url is not found then I want to show an error message instead of showing "The requested url is not found". How I will do this? Please help me.

Comment: use a conditional statement and echo, or make a modification to your `.htaccess` file. Did you not research this first?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess url-rewrite if file not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469955/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-file-not-exists)

Comment: You didn't put any effort in this whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your web directory, and write the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
```

Make sure to replace notfound.html with your custom 404 html file.

Comment: Question's that show no effort shouldn't be answered, IMHO and shared by many.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that but it will not work for me because several user will use my extensions. so I have to fix it in code stage. if you have better solution in that stage then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

$headers=get_headers($url);

Then check if $result[0] contains 200 OK (which means the file is there)

A function to check if a URL works could be this:

```
function UR_exists($url)
{
   $headers=get_headers($url);
   return stripos($headers[0],"200 OK")?true:false;
}
```

/* You can test a URL like this (sample) */

```
if(UR_exists("https://www.example.com/"))
   echo "This page exists";
else
   echo "This page does not exist";
```

Hope this will help you out.