# How to redirect sub-directory to root directory with parameter as sub-directory using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Want to Redirect to index.php

When user try to come at site using any URL like:

1)www.domain.com/xyz

2)www.domain.com/abc

3)www.domain.com/apple

4)www.domain.com/123

5)www.domain.com/hello

Whatever random text at the end of the URL.

I want .htaccess code which redirects those URL to
www.domain.com/index.php

index.php contain code to get data using GET method so the last string of URL needs to get in index.php file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?parameter=$1
```

I tried this code but it goes in infinite redirect.
I want to stop loop while parameter found.

Comment: You should probably simply limit this to rewrite only if what was requested did not match a physically existing folder or file - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469955/htaccess-url-rewrite-if-file-not-exists

Comment: there is no directory or file there. it always random text. need some code which defines rule if parameter available in URL then no need to redirect.

Comment: Yes there _is_ - your index.php for example. You are getting a redirect loop, _because_ `index.php` matches `^(.*)$` again in the next round of rewriting. So if you _exclude_ existing files from this … problem most likely solved already.

Comment: Thank you it solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be redirecting to a relative address (assuming that index.php is on the same domain). Also, you need to exclude existing files:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" code solve my problem